# why gcc does not report warning about uninitialized value?

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class A {
public:
        A(char* buf, int len, bool own)
                : buf_(own? new char[len_] : buf_)
                   // Note that the above expression either uses `len_` (which is
                   // not yet initialized), or buf_ (which is the variable we are
                   // trying to initialize).  In both cases, the parameter 
                   // (len or buf) should have been used.
                , len_(len)
                , own_(own) {
                printf("buf=%p, buf_=%p\n", buf, buf_);
                if(own_) memcpy(buf_, buf, len);
        }
        ~A() {
                printf("%02x\n", buf_[0]);
                if(own_) delete[] buf_;
        }
private:
        char* const buf_;
        int const len_;
        bool const own_;
};

int main() {
        char buf[100] = {0};
        A a(buf, (int)sizeof(buf), true);
        return 0;
}
```

obviously, line :

> buf_(own? new char[len_] : buf_)

use uninitialized value len_ and buf_.

I compile it by

> g++ a.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Winit-self
>   -Wmaybe-uninitialized

What make me very confused is gcc does not report any warning about the uninitialized member `buf_` and `len_`.

Which gcc option can produce a warning in this scenario?

Update:

> g++-6 does not warn, g++-7 -O1 warns about len_, g++-8 -O0 and clang++
>   warn about both len_ and buf_. – Marc Glisse

Comment: add `-O3`? With gcc-7 that gives a warning.

Comment: why should there be a warning for `len_` ?

Comment: ..ups now I get it. But nevertheless it would be nice if you explain in the question why you expect the warning. It isnt too obvious

Comment: @tobi303 I just wasted 1 hour to analyze a core dump file, and in final, I found some code like that.

Comment: I would have expected `-Wuninitialized` (which is part of `-Wall`) to catch this, but apparently it does not. Might be worth a bug report to gcc. clang actually does give a proper warning in this case.

Comment: imo this is one of the problems using `_` where the names are too similar. In initialization lists I think it pays to use the same names (because the compiler just does the right thing) or use distinctively different names (because less human error).

Comment: To clarify: g++-6 does not warn, g++-7 -O1 warns about len_, g++-8 -O0 and clang++ warn about both len_ and buf_.

Comment: @alpha I didnt mean explain in the sense of "why would it be useful to have a warning" but "why is the code wrong". Its not only the compiler that easily can overlook that mistake ;)

Comment: @tobi303 Please forgive my poor English. I just misunderstand your post...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Very thanks, I will try gcc7 and clang.

Comment: Using same name for parameter and member would have avoided this problem...:)

Comment: Using std::string instead of [ char*,  int ] would have avoided this problem.

Comment: Quitting your current job and going to work on a different code base would *also* have fixed the problem but that doesn't really explain *why* the problem occurred :-)

Comment: Did you consider reporting this as a defect to the [gcc-bugs mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/) before writing about it here? Just sayin', generally speaking, all questions beginning with "why ..." are of dubious relevance on this network. Please consider reading the entirety of the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking future questions.

Comment: Why does this have four up-votes? Is StackOverflow a catalog of bug reports, now? Is that what we, as a community, want to encourage? People asking about bugs here, rather than in the correct place? It must be rare to see an emoji on SO, yet this is necessary to convey my face right now... D:<